# What is the difference between "Must" and "Must be"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw the following sentences in an advertisement.

- Graduation must be in computer science.
- Graduation is must.

I want to know the meaning of Must and Must be and the difference between them.

Answer (score 3):

> *Graduation is must.

This is simply not grammatical. The correct version is:

> Graduation is [a must](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/a+must).

Then for:

> Graduation must be in computer science.

This means that if you graduate, it should not be in anything else than computer science.

I don't think that is what is actually meant - I assume that what is meant is this:

> Graduation is a must in computer science.

or

> Graduation is [a must-have](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/must-have) in computer science.

Meaning that when you study computer science, you must see it through to graduation.

Comment: You mean to say that Graduation is Must is not grammatical. but i have seen somewhere written it.

Comment: That it is written "somewhere" does not mean it is grammatical. I often see things like "it was they're fault" written, but that doesn't make it correct. Was the source were you saw it written a very authoritative source for standard English?

Comment: Not everything that people write is grammatical or in line with accepted conventions.